# How do I repair my sliding window latch and pull that doesn't lock?

Tags: repair, windows

I recently moved into an old condo made in 1976 that has two horizontal sliding windows (~34"x28" panes). Both have a lock/latch mechanism that doesn't seem to latch onto anything at all - the window still slides whether you are pulling the latch or the edge of the frame. The latches seem to be spring loaded and will return to their position after being pulled then released. What parts are missing or possibly defective on the latches and how is it supposed to work?
[image]

Comment: Is that hooked secion on the right side of the latch supposed to hook around the edge of the right pane?

Comment: In the near term, an appropriate length of broomstick or large dowel to drop into the frame channel and hold the windw closed is what most people use on this sort of window, as the latches are not that reliable or sturdy.